# Firebase retrieve data from a node based on info from another node in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working on an app for sports and I'm investigating if/how Firebase can handle the data and relationships I need.

The user logins into the app and goes to a Dashboard, which lists all the Pools he is participating in.

The current data structure for in Firebase is this:

```
  {
  Game:
     78765: {
          teamA: 'New York',
          teamB: 'Montreal',
          date:  '20170601',
          etc...
     },
     76421: {
          teamA: 'LA',
          teamB: 'Mexico',
          date:  '20170602',
          etc...
     }
  },
  {
  Pool: 
     12345: {
          GameID: 78765,                      <- GameId from above
          PoolName: 'MyPool',
          Owner: 'LpWgezRkC6EWS0sjXEWxhFl2'   <- UserId
          etc...
     }
  },
  {
  PlayerInPool: {
      DUmwewIfzAbfWZN4NjS8mhX82   <- UserId
          12345: true             <- PoolId from above
      LpWgezRkC6EWS0sjXEWxhFl2    
          12345: true       
      etc...              
      }
  }
```

How would I go about pulling the pool information to display on the users Dashboard?

What needs to be displayed in each cell in the UICollectionView is the Pool info (PoolName and PoolOwner) with the Game information like the TeamA and TeamB names along with the Game date.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use firebase. I'm fairly new to programming and I caught on in no time. think JSON when you think of your structure and they encourage you to make it as flat as possible (as opposed to lots of nesting). Good Luck! Here is one idea of what your structure might look like.

```
"GameTitle":{
        “PlayerInPool":{ 
             "PoolID":"12345",
            “UserID”:“email@address.com”,
            “Status”:“Active”
            }
        “Pool":{ 
             "PoolID":"12345",
            “PoolName”:“myPoolName”,
            “GameID”:“547324”
            }
        “Game":{ 
             "PlayerID1":"43623",
            “PlayerID2”:“23567”,
            “GameID”:“myGame”,
            “GameName”:“myGame12345”
            }
    }
```